# How to use UPDATE,SELECT,WHERE,AND MYSQL clauses in 1 statement

Tags: c#

Currently, I have 2 different functions where one function is:

```
        public void CHECKHWID()
        {
            try
            {
                string server = "72.167.59.139";
                string database = "yourdatabasename";
                string uid = "youruid";
                string password = "yourpassword";
                string ssl = "None";
                string connectionString = $"SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PASSWORD={password};SSL Mode={ssl};";
                using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();
                using var command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE core_members SET member_hwid = @hwid WHERE name = @name", connection);
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", maskedTextBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hwid", HWIDNumber);
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", maskedTextBox1.Text);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //var hashedPassword = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ISSUE IS: " + ex);
            }
        }
```

and then this function:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string server = "72.167.59.139";
        string database = "yourdatabasename";
        string uid = "youruserid";
        string password = "yourpassword";
        string ssl = "None";
        string connectionString = $"SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PASSWORD={password};SSL Mode={ssl};";  
        using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        using var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT members_pass_hash FROM core_members WHERE name = @name AND mgroup_others = 7 AND member_hwid = @hwid;", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", maskedTextBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hwid", HWIDNumber);

        var hashedPassword = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            if (!(hashedPassword is null && !BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(maskedTextBox2.Text, hashedPassword)))
            {
                //using var command2 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE core_members SET member_hwid = @hwid WHERE name = @name", connection);

                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default.username = maskedTextBox1.Text;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.password = maskedTextBox2.Text;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                }
                var vip = new vipmember();
                //CHECKHWID();
                vip.Show();
                HM();
                connection.Close();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error is: " + ex);
            //MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex);
            MessageBox.Show("Either you have entered the wrong login information, you are not VIP, or your HWID does not match.");
            MessageBox.Show("Please Copy and Paste this message and give it to the owner: " + HWIDNumber + " Select this MessageBox and press Ctrl + c to Copy it's content!");
            //MessageBox.Show("Either Login information is Incorrect or You are not VIP.");               
        }

        //CHECKHWID();
    }
```

What is occuring is when I try to run both select and update at once, i am having a "fake account created", which then sets the hwid. When I run them both; it sets the HWID as intended but i'm wanting to run it to where it sets the HWID first and then runs the SELECT query as you see in the 2nd function. I want to be able to eliminate the 1st function and be able to update the database to set the hwid to each user on startup, then check the hwid as soon as they try to log in. How can I make it to where the 2nd function updates the user's hwid on the database, then run the select query?

As explained above, how can I merge function 1 into function 2 or into just 1 query?

Comment: why not just run the query sequentially in one function?
move the other one to run after the other query is done

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedure.

```
// mysql procedure code
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS p_updateAndSelectMember;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    PROCEDURE p_updateAndSelectMember(
    _hwid INT,
    _name VARCHAR(32)
    )
    BEGIN
        -- update
        UPDATE core_members SET member_hwid = _hwid WHERE core_members.name = _name;
        -- select
        SELECT members_pass_hash FROM core_members WHERE NAME = _name AND member_hwid = _hwid;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;


// c# code
using var command = new MySqlCommand("CALL p_updateAndSelectMember(@hwid, @name)", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hwid", HWIDNumber);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", maskedTextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: How can I write it though, to where it updates database, but only runs the update query if the column is empty for that user?

Comment: You can use following code
`DECLARE _oldHwid TINYINT DEFAULT 1;
SELECT ISNULL(member_hwid) FROM core_members WHERE NAME = _name INTO _oldHwid;
IF _oldHwid = 1 THEN
 UPDATE core_members SET member_hwid = _hwid WHERE core_members.name = _name;
END IF;
SELECT members_pass_hash FROM core_members WHERE NAME = _name AND member_hwid = _hwid;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following procedure code

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `test`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `p_updateAndSelectMember`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p_updateAndSelectMember`(
    _hwid INT,
    _name VARCHAR(32)
    )
BEGIN
        DECLARE _oldHwid TINYINT DEFAULT 1;
        SELECT ISNULL(member_hwid) FROM core_members WHERE NAME = _name INTO _oldHwid;
        IF _oldHwid = 1 THEN
            -- update
            UPDATE core_members SET member_hwid = _hwid WHERE core_members.name = _name;
        END IF;
        -- select
        SELECT members_pass_hash FROM core_members WHERE NAME = _name AND member_hwid = _hwid;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why are you posting 2 answers? and both answers do not seem to help OP since they lack details and explanation